# VB.NET - MessageBox YesNo Conditional Statement not working

Tags: vb.net

I have a program where I am clearing out comboboxes that the user is using to answer multiple choice questions.  If the user clicks Clear, a messagebox pops up and asks the user if they are sure they want to clear out the form.  If they press yes, it clears out all comboboxes.  As of right now, if the user presses no, it still clears out the comboboxes.

Code:

```
  Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

    MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to clear your answers?", "Attention!",             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        For Each cbo As ComboBox In Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
            cbo.Items.Clear()
        Next
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This will never work because `Yes = 6`. As of now your condition looks like this: `If (6 = True) Then`. You need to catch the return value from `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: kudos for using `MessageBox.Show` versus MsgBox though!

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture the MessageBox result:

```
Dim dlgR as DialogResult

DlgR = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to clear your answers?", 
            "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

' then test it:
If dlgR = DialogResult.Yes Then
    For Each cbo As ComboBox In Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
        cbo.Items.Clear()
    Next
End If
```

`MessageBox` is a function which returns a `DialogResult`.  Your code

```
If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then...
```

isnt evaluating the user's response; `DialogResult.Yes` is not False (0), so it will always be True and cause the CBOs to be cleared no matter what they answer.

Also, that code is not legal under `Option Strict`.  VB/VS would inform you of this and prompt you to change it if `Option Strict` is on; this will avoid many similar - and more serious - errors elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly

Wow, I just realized that cbo.Items.Clear() clears out combobox drowndownlist contents.  

Is there a way to just clear the user's selection, but keep the contents? (contents are A, B, C, and D) multiple choice questions

Comment: I wondered why you were removing the answers list... change `Items.Clear` to `.Text = ""`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method also:

```
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear your answers?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        cbo.Items.Clear()
    Else
        'false condition to be executed
    End If
```

Note: To clear combo box items you need not to use a iterative loop  `cbo.Items.Clear()` will clear the item list of combo box

If you want to remove a particular item from you can use two methods

- Based on the `item`

  `cbo.Items.Remove("Item As string")`

**Example:**  `cbo.Items.Remove("Apple")`

- Based on `Index`

  `cbo.Items.RemoveAt(Index As Integer)`

**Example:** `cbo.Items.RemoveAt(2)`

Comment: I prefer this methodology, as the dialogresult is 'garbage collected' after evaluation, instead of keeping it in memory for the scope below the if statement. Also looks cleaner.

Comment: @Chad You do know `MsgBox` is a wrapped function which in the end calls `MessageBox.Show`? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Interaction.vb#555

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I was not referring to `MsgBox` in my previous comment; I was referring to removing the `Dim` statement for the `DialogResult` (which the other answer has). It's cleaner to have the one calculation in the if statement without a Dim as it means less code, and you don't need to check the result more than once (so no need to keep it in memory).

Comment: @Chad Ah, I see what you mean now. I agree it's cleaner but I think Plutonix tried to point out that `Show` is a function which returns a `DialogResult`. Also, I don't like to see people encouraging others to use those old vb functions like `MsgBox`, `InStr`, `Len` etc.