# My VB.net Code is working but it's displaying errors afterwards

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

I've written some code in vb.net that adds, deletes and updates a spreadsheet. The add and the delete button works excellently without bring up any errors. But the update button works but it brings an error afterwards. Can someone help me know what's the problem and help me fix it? Any help will be appreciated.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Welcome
Private Sub ImportExceldata(DataExcelFile As String, ImportData As DataGridView)



    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) Then
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DataExcelFile & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CandidatesCallCenterLocation$]", MyConnection)
            'MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Attendace")
            dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
            ImportData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)


            MyConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1) Then
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DataExcelFile & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [ExpectedNumberofCalls$]", MyConnection)
            'MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Attendace")
            dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
            ImportData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(2) Then
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DataExcelFile & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CostProcessingTelephoneCalls$]", MyConnection)
            'MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Attendace")
            dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
            ImportData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ImportExceldata("C:\Users\Home\Desktop\dss.xlsx", DataGridView)

End Sub
```

The above code imports the spreadsheets to the DatagridView.It works fine. I haven't encountered any problems so far here.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView.SelectedRows
        DataGridView.Rows.Remove(row)
    Next
End Sub
```

The code above deletes rows in the spreadsheet. No problems have been encountered so far.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) Then
        Try
            Dim x As Integer
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(0).Value = ACTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(1).Value = MATextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(2).Value = AFCTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(3).Value = TextBoxWPH.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1) Then
        Try
            Dim a As Integer
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(a).Cells(0).Value = ACTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(a).Cells(1).Value = RegionTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(a).Cells(2).Value = ENCTextBox.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(2) Then
        Try
            Dim b As Integer

            DataGridView.Rows.Item(b).Cells(0).Value = ACTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(b).Cells(1).Value = RegionTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(b).Cells(2).Value = ENCTextBox.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above adds data to any column that you want to add data to. But the only situation here is that the add button replaces the whole row instead of adding a new row to the spreadsheet. But it cause any problems.Otherwise there are no more problems that I've encountered so far.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim AreaCode, MetropolitanArea As String
    Dim AnnualFixedArea, WagePerHour As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    MsgBox("Do you want to update the records?")
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) Then
        Try
            AreaCode = ACTextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(0).Value = ACTextBox.Text
            MetropolitanArea = MATextBox.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(1).Value = MATextBox.Text
            AnnualFixedArea = AFCTextBox.Text

            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(2).Value = AFCTextBox.Text
            WagePerHour = TextBoxWPH.Text
            DataGridView.Rows.Item(x).Cells(3).Value = TextBoxWPH.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1) Then
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

This is where the error is displaying after I update the columns. Only the part where AreaCode = ACTextBox.Text works. The other textbox work but after I click the update button, it displays the following errors.

https://ibb.co/JdzGmfp
https://ibb.co/QmnwJZr

Thanks

Comment: @LarsTech, your update method does not show where you are tracking the record you want to update. Try and get the row by a unique ID and update that row using the ID

Comment: @Borntocode Not my post.  I just added a tag.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I just checked it

Comment: @spirit check the previous comment

Comment: @Spirit 1) Comment out the Try..Catch part to let it tell you exactly which line the error happens on. 2) The value of `x` is not set, so it is 0. 3) Please give the controls meaningful names, like btnUpdate, btnAdd, and so on.

Comment: @Andrew Morton. Oh. I thought he was telling LarsTech. Let me try to comment it out.

Comment: @Spirit Then you should google for the error message "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid", the results of which I think will make the problem clear to you.

Comment: @Andrew Morton. The update seems to have a problem. I can only update one cell

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @Spirit Also, the MsgBox used in the code only gives the option of "OK". You probably want something more like the code shown in this answer: [VB.NET - MessageBox YesNo Conditional Statement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25610455/1115360).